# dynamically load resource file

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I want to dynamically load a resource file.

If i do it statically, it obviously works well:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources._88);
player.Play();
```

This loads and plays the resource _88.

However, I want this to be dynamically,

I have a variable 'num' which can be any number from 1-90, and i want to load the resource related to that number.

So I create another variable called 'soundURL' which looks like:

```
var soundURL = "_" + num;
```

But when I use that with the previous it obviously doesnt work:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.soundURL);
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the ResourceManager to load resources by name

```
object O = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_88");
```

You then just need to cast it as a Stream..

```
var s = (Stream)O;
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(s);
player.Play();
```

Answer (score 2):

If that's a resx resource file, you can get the resource value using ResourceManager

```
var soundURL=Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("_" + num);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
    string file = "_" + num;

    SoundPlayer sp;
    Stream s = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream(file);
    if (s != null)
    {
        sp = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(s);
        sp.Play();
    }
```