# C# add method groups 1 by 1 to view list then execution list with contains method groups - only separated method no dynamically

Tags: c#, queue

For better explanation here is a GUI  screenshoot :

SCREEN GUI ( can't add small image only link)
[image]

And here is a all of my code with comments :

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media; // to play sounds


namespace Music_PLayer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //List View
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

            // Columns CONSTRUCT
            listView1.Columns.Add("ID", 70);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Music name", 150);

            //combobox  items
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 1");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 2");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 3");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 4");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Music 5");
        }

        // ADD TO List VIEW
        private void add(int ID, string name_music)
        {
            string[] row = { Convert.ToString(ID), name_music };

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);

            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }

        //button to delete selected items in list view
        private void button_delete_selected_music_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                listView1.SelectedItems[0].Remove();
            }
            catch { }

        }
**//EDITED :**
        // buttton to add music to list view
        int i = 0;
        private void button_add_music_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex==0)
        {
            dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 1", playmusic1);
            add(i, comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 2", playmusic2);
            add(i, comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 3", playmusic3);
            add(i, comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 4", playmusic4);
            add(i, comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 4)
        {
            dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 5", playmusic5);
            add(i, comboBox1.Text);
        }

        }

        // button to start music
        private void button_start_music(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        // Voids with music :
        public void playmusic1()
        {

            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound1);
            audio.Play();
        }
        public void playmusic2()
        {
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound2);
            audio.Play();
        }
        public void playmusic3()
        {
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound3);
            audio.Play();

        }
            public void playmusic4()
            {
                SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound4);
                audio.Play();
            }
            public void playmusic5()
            {
                SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(Music_PLayer.Properties.Resources.playsound5);
                audio.Play();
            }
                public delegate void PlayMusic();
// EDITED 
        Dictionary<string, PlayMusic> dictOfDelegate = new Dictionary<string, PlayMusic>();

        void CreateList()
        {
        dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 1", playmusic1);
        dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 2", playmusic2);
        dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 3", playmusic3);
        dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 4", playmusic4);
        dictOfDelegate.Add("Music 5", playmusic5);
        }

    void InvokeMethod(string item)
    {
        PlayMusic method = dictOfDelegate.First(x => x.Key == item).Value;

        method.Invoke();
    }
    }
}
```

I want to to select a song from the combobox to add it to the playlist that will play from top to bottom after clicking on the "Start Music" button..

I would like to add a selected song from the combobox to the listview when you click the "Add Music to list" button. Of course, with the "Delete selected music" button I have the ability to delete a song from the list.

So I have to do so for example when I select from the combobox (Music1) click on the button (Add Music to list), it will display ID 1 Music name Music 1 and when click on the Start Music button it will execute void playmusic1 ();

I know I just only add text from combobox to listview but i don't know how can I get method there...

I really don't know how to code Start Music button ( i thinking about queue) to play music one by one with my listView1.

All I need is Collection or something or Queue.

If I dont explain exacly just ask..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really, *really* don't want to have a separate method to play each possible sound - that'll be a maintenance nightmare to say the least.

One thing you *could* do is [dynamically load things from resource files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663329/dynamically-load-resource-file). The linked question has an example specifically for sound player.

From the accepted answer, do the following to dynamically retrieve the resource:

```
object o = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("whateverName");
```

You then cast it to a stream and play the audio.

You don't necessarily have to use a resource file, though - if you know where the sounds are, you could easily just retrieve a list of file names in the folder(s) in the questions.

**Edit:** If you really want separate methods, you could always use a Dictionary to map the sound name to the method to run. Something along the lines of this script I put together in LINQpad:

```
void Main()
{
    var db = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
    db.Add("Music 1", PlaySound1);

    // Retrieve the method we're looking for and execute it
    db["Music 1"]();
}

private void PlaySound1()
{
    // Play the sound
}
```

You *could* also do a `switch` statement:

```
switch (soundName) {
   case "Music 1":
       // Play music 1
       break;
   case "Music 2":
       // Play music 2
       break;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: You are right i can do that  dynamically , but i want do this as i said , i have another program with separated methods too and i  just need this! How can i do that with separate methods

Comment: Sorry for this but i need just in separated methods. Caould you be patient and just exaplain how can i do that? Thank you for your pleasure.

Comment: @Michael I edited - you could use a Dictionary to map the name of the sound to the method to run if you'd like.

Comment: as i see Dictionary but i don't see usage this in my problem. It don't give a point to do what i want i finally result. All i want to do is select Music 1 , add Music 1 to list View , add Music 4 to list View and when i press Start Music it gonna just play this selected musics 1 and 4 for ie. I understand you give me right example I'm thank you very much but can you say something about it or give example this what i looking for?  just sample on my code please if you can . Again thank you very much

Comment: i added your code to main code just look first post. Anyway could you check i did it correct?I edited my button_add_music please look on it too. And i have trouble when i add for example: Music 1 and again Music 1 it's display a bug and can't add 2 the same music to my list. 2nd problem is how should i write correctly my button_start_music . Could you help a little? Thank you anyway.